# parfor in MATLAB : aborted workers

Tags: matlab, for-loop, parallel-processing, compiler-errors, matlab-deployment

I'm using MATLAB 2016a on win 10 64bit OS. I run my program which is almost a complicated simulation of an engineering problem.

Question is that i use parfor and there is 2 other for loops in this program. I've been cautious to use minimum for loops and using array smart and built in commands such as repmat, bsxfun and etc. to avoid for loops. when i run the program it goes quite a while nice and stores results for me but suddenly after some iterations i encounter this error:

"All workers aborted during execution of the parfor loop."

and program terminates. I'm using a powerful system with these specs:
corei7 CPU intel 4720HQ, 16 GB RAM DDR4, 8MB cache, GPU: Geforce GTX 970M.

An example will be like this (although main program is very more demanding from both memory and computational point of view and I've omitted many lines and also 3 functions are called which are not included here):

```
lambda = 5e-5;
tau = 10.^((-5:25)*0.1);
tau = 0.3;
eta = 1.5;
b = 0.3;
c = 0.4;
beta = (0:90)';
x  = (0.01:1000+0.01)';
r = (80.21:800+80.21)';
h = (10:0.1:30.5)';
Lh = length(h);
Lr = length(r);
Lx = length(x);
N = 6;
binom_coeff = factorial(N)*ones(N,1)./(factorial((1:N)').*factorial((N(1:N))'));
pdf_x = 2*pi*x*lambda.*exp(-pi*lambda*x.^2);
pdf_R = 2*pi*lambda*r.*exp(-pi*lambda*r.^2);

    theta_l = atan(repmat(h,1,Lr)./repmat(r',Lh,1))*180/pi;
    ratio = sqrt(repmat(h,1,Lr)+repmat(r',Lh,1));
    coverage = zeros(size(beta_m));
    Integrand_x = zeros(size(x));
    Y = (b*h+c)*(1-a);
    for k=1:length(beta_m)
        for thr = 1:length(tau)
            parfor i=1:Lx
                   temp = (-1)*eta*tau(thr)*(G_l/G_0.*( ratio/sqrt(x(i)^2+h_0^2)).^(-v));
                   temp_N = repmat(temp,1,N).*reshape(repmat(1:N,size(temp,1)*size(temp,2),1),size(temp,1),size(temp,2)*N);
                    Integrand = (1-(trapz(h,exp(temp_N).*repmat(Y,1,Lr*N))))';
                    Integrand_x(i) = exp(trapz(r,(Integrand * binom_coeff)));                           
             end
           coverage(thr,k) = trapz(x,pdf_x.*Integrand_x);
        end
   end
savepar =     ['FinalMainRes_longheiv',num2str(v),'h0',num2str(h_0),'a',num2str(a),'.mat'];
save(savepar)
```

It's worth to mention that running with just one worker does not crush (although it took about 4 days to complete the run).

What is the problem and how can i prevent it. Any help is appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: That error means the workers crashed while executing the loop. What happens if you run only a single worker? (I.e. `parpool('local', 1)`) Are there any crash dump files on your machine?

Comment: good experiment. I have to run this too. thank for advise. I'll tell you the results in 2 or 3 days

Comment: Hello again. sorry for delay. at last run completed. no error occurred with one worker.